# Retrofits call.enqueue is blocking for the first request

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 in an Android Application written in Kotlin for calling an API.
My call looks as follows:

```
val time = measureTimeMillis {
    val call = geocodingApi.searchByName("Berlin")
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<GeocodingResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>?, response: Response<GeocodingResponse>?) {
          // some code
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GeocodingResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
          // some code
        }

    })
}
Timber.d("searching by name took $time ms")
```

The geocodingApi is initialised in the constructor of my class as follows:

```
val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger { Timber.d(it) })
loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS

val client = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(GoogleApiKeyInterceptor())
        .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()))
        .client(client)
        .build()

geocodingApi = retrofit.create(GeocodingApi::class.java)
```

The initialisation takes around 80ms, which is acceptable. The problem is, that the first call takes between 1.5 and 2 seconds blocking the UI Thread. All subsequent calls return directly and invoke the callback some time later when the call is finished. The logs look like this:

```
searching by name took 1864 ms
searching by name took 3 ms
searching by name took 4 ms
searching by name took 2 ms
```

Wrapping all calls in a separate thread would be possible and produces the expected result (no UI-blocking), but according to the documentation calling `call.enqueue` should execute the result in the background by itself,  and it works for all but the first call.
Am I doing anything wrong? I am using Retrofit 2.3.0 and OkHttp 3.8.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @yaneq6 Unfortunately not. I tracked the problem down to be caused by the MoshiConverterFactory and switched to Gson which works. I created an issue at the moshi github page, maybe you can comment there that you have the same problem: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the additional library [Kotshi](https://github.com/ansman/kotshi) and use it instead of the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory`. Kotshi uses kapt to analyse the annotation at compile time avoiding the huge overhead of parsing the annotations at runtime.

Within the Retrofit Builder the only necessary step is to replace
`.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()))`
by
`.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(ApplicationJsonAdapterFactory.INSTANCE).build()))`

And all data classes used as serializable models should be annotated with `@JsonSerializable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(/* your url */)
    .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    // other builder options...
    .build();
```

Use `callbackExecutor` while using Retrofit.